# Neural network time series app processes values out of range of data

Tags: matlab

I want to customize my neural network training to process within the range of [0,65] - I tried the code:

```
net.inputs{1}.processParams;
ymin = 0;
ymax = 65;

net.outputs{2}.processParams;
ymin = 0;
ymax = 65;
```

Yet when I check the Time Series-Response graph it still processes values beyond these two values.

Using:

```
SampleData:
18
39
51
26
13
9
13
 9
 13
 13
 13
 4 
 46 
 52
 52
 8

T = tonndata(SampleData,false,false);
trainFcn = 'trainbr';
feedbackDelays = 1:2;
hiddenLayerSize = 400;
net = narnet(feedbackDelays,hiddenLayerSize, 'open', trainFcn);
[x,xi,ai,li] = preparets(net,{},{},T);

net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;
```

then....to scale the training processing...

```
 net.inputs{1}.processParams;
ymin = 0;
ymax = 65;

net.outputs{2}.processParams;
ymin = 0;
ymax = 65;
```

Comment: **How** are you training your neural network? Those variables and parameters don't mean anything.

Comment: Using backward propagation